# How to set AutomateIt to active a task in "AND" or "OR" condition?

Tags: automation

I want to make my smart phone smarter and I try AutomateIt because it is free. However, I don't know how to make it run a task when the task needs multiple conditions trigger. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple triggers are supported on AutomateIt Pro:
http://automateitapp.com/index.php/user-guide-2/composite-triggers-actions-pro-version-only/

As of version 3.0.54 (released on Feb 2013), you can unlock Pro features from within the free version.

Read here how to unlock features:
http://automateitapp.com/new-release-rich-notification-unlock-pro-features-and-more/